# select all checkboxes inside ul

Tags: jquery

I would like to understand.

Why this will not work:

```
$(this).closest("li").find("ul:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

But this will?

```
$(this).closest("li").find("ul").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Thanks

Comment: Props for using the `.prop()` method (no pun intended) rather than `.attr()`. I can't tell you how many times I see people using the wrong method in this case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue in your first example is because of `ul:checkbox`. This looks for `<ul>` elements which are also checkboxes, which is not possible. You need a space between those selectors, or to use `find()` as you are in the second example.

Either of these will work:

```
$(this).closest("li").find("ul :checkbox").prop("checked", true);
// or
$(this).closest("li").find("ul").find(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```